# Why there's delay in Network Stats manager Statistics?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, kotlin, networking

I am currently trying to measure the bandwidth consumed by a piece of code in android. Whenever I am calling the `networkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice()`, it is returning data value that is same for a particular period of time.

Here is the code sample:

```kotlin
networkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice(
    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI,
    "",
    0,
    System.currentTimeMillis()
)
```

Can anyone confirm that after how much time the latest data is updated in `NetworkStatsManager`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179382/android-networkstats-bucket-data-not-updating

Comment: @Enowneb I am asking for the refresh time of NetworkStatsmanager, or a way to track this. The thread you shared doesn't has it.